# Discord code stops running when using client.run (Python)

Tags: python, discord.py

All the code I have here is within another loop but when I run the code it stops as soon as it hits the bot.run line. It sends the message once it hits that bot.run line. I can't put that line at the end of the code because the loop I was talking about is an endless loop that doesn't stop. I need to send the message within the loop. What can I do?

```
  @bot.event  
  async def on_ready():
        bb = 1
        g = 0
        while g <= len(NewProdNames) - 1:

            if g == 2:
                bb = 2 - 5

            print('{0.user} is online!'.format(bot))
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Archive Restock", description=NewProdNames[g],
                                color=discord.Color.from_rgb(3, 236, 252))
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-results-container"]/div[' + str(productNumbers[g] + bb) + ']/div/div[1]/a[1]/img').get_attribute('data-image-first'))
            embed.set_footer(text="Archive Restock Monitor | VirtualKicks",
                                 icon_url='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0269/8146/6177/files/Mooi_large.jpg')
            await bot.get_channel(Channel id).send(embed=embed)

            g = g + 1


   bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Rewrite your code, what you're trying simply doesn't work (looping the `bot.run()` function).

Comment: But what can I do, I need the bot to send messages multiple times, its an endless loop

Comment: You dont need to start the bot in a loop. Just call `bot.run()` at the very bottom and start your loop in the `on_ready` event function.

Comment: Maybe if you provided more information on what exactly you want to do I might help you better.

Comment: I am building a webscraping bot that checks for sneaker restocks on a website, as soon as it send's a notification on the restock, it needs to keep on running the code and check again for the next restock.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event()
async def on_ready():
    await someFunction()


async def someFunction():
    # some Code
    await someFunction() # Use recursion

bot.run("token")
```